# Solving system of recurrence relations

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, exponentiation

Base Case:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
T(1) = 1 \\ T(2) = 1 \\T(3) = 4\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I have the system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
T(N) = G(N-1) + F(N-1) \\
G(N) = F(N-1) + G(N-1) \\
F(N) = 2H(N-1) + F(N-2) \\
H(N) = H(N-1) + F(N-1)\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I seems $$T(N) = H(N) = G(N)$$ so we now have only two equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
T(N) = T(N-1) + F(N-1) \\
F(N) = 2T(N-1) + F(N-2)\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I figured

$T(N) = T(N-k) + \sum_{i=1}^k F(N-i) $

and

$F(N) = F(N-2) +2T(N-k) + 2\sum_{i=2}^k F(N-i) $

But after mixing these expressions in a similar way, I came unstuck.

I tried following [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21538/solving-a-set-of-recurrence-relations) but it didn't help.

I would like to find $T(10^{12})$. Probably by using matrix exponentiation.

Comment: use latex please.....

Comment: Ok, I'm just reading a latex tutorial now, will update soon

Comment: I've now added latex

Comment: NICE!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: fixed a typo, it should have been F(N-2) not F(N-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
T_n \\
F_n \\
F_{n - 1}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
T_{n-1}\\
F_{n-1}\\
F_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So starting with $(T_1, F_1, F_0)$ you can find $(T_n, F_n, F_{n-1})$ quickly by matrix exponentiation.  The latter can be done by the squaring method.

Comment: beautifully simple isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T(N)=T(N-1)+F(N-1)$
so
$$2T(N)=2T(N-1)+2F(N-1)$$
minus this $F(N)=2T(N-1)+F(N-1)$
you get
$$2T(N)-F(N)=F(N-1)$$
which means
$$T(N)=\frac{1}{2}(F(N)+F(N-1))$$
so by institution it back to $F(N)=2T(N-1)+F(N-2)$ for $N-1$, you get
$$F(N)=F(N-1)+2F(N-2)$$
Using the base case we have
$$2T(1)=F(1)+F(0)=2$$
Also
$$2T(2)=F(2)+F(1)=F(1)+2F(0)+F(1)=2(F(1)+F(0))=2$$
So there is an inconsistency in the base case you gave.

Comment: would you like to take this to private chat quickly? (if math.stackexchange has that feature)

Comment: Don;t know how to do a chat. I think if you can find the initial values for F, then it maybe solved.

Comment: I think T(3) should be 3. I formulated all my equations incorrectly  btw (for what i was trying to solve). I know how to correct everything though.